# ReactJS + babelJS + Webpack + fails on Android 4.0.x

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I spent a day debugging our ReactJS app build using the very common combination of `webpack` and `babeljs` under Android `4.0.3` (~3 yo).

2 problems will probably arise for anybody in this situation:

1. The app code will just fail to load throwing an error about `readonly __esModule property can't be overwritten`
2. Touch events won't trigger. Clicking a button, link etc.. will just break throwing `illegal use constructor`

Comment: Are you also using redux by any chance? I only seem to get this error when third party libraries have compiled loosely.

Comment: I was indeed. The solutions below fixed the issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The first** problem, the `__esModule` thing comes from babel way of implementing ES6 modules using:

`Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {value: true});`

This seems very broken on Android 4.0.x.

The workaround is to enable `babel` loose mode on `es6.modules`. You can add this on your `.babelrc`: `"loose": ["es6.modules"]` or refer to the [doc](https://developit.github.io/babel-legacy-docs//docs/advanced/loose/#usage) for CLI instruction.

**The second** problem is due to [`new Event('stuff')`](https://developit.github.io/babel-legacy-docs//docs/advanced/loose/#usage) instructions in React source code. As this code is only wrapped in `if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {}`, you want to ensure `process.env.NODE_ENV` value is set to `"production"`.

When using `webpack`, this can be done quite easily achieved using the [`DefinePLugin`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin)

```
// in your webpack config:
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
    })
],
```

If you want the value to actually reflect `env`, just write the dirty but working:

`'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '"'`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was able to solve everything on webpack `config-make.js` file:

```
var loaders = {
        "js": ""babel-loader?loose=all""
};

plugins: [
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
})],
```