# Cannot assign to read only property '__esModule'

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs, redux

When compiling a React and Redux application with Webpack and Babel I get:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '__esModule' of #<Object>`

In some older browsers (<= Chrome 1, Android 4, Safari 5).

This issue seems to stem from [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) and [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) outputting the line `exports.__esModule = true;` in the `lib` build but my application using `Object.defineProperty` instead (because they [build loosely](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/babel6-loose-mode.html) and I do not).

Two solutions are:

1. Building my application in `loose` mode also.
2. Importing `react-redux/src` and `redux/src` and building it with the same .babelrc as the application (everything is not loose).

As long as they are consistent and both:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
```

and `exports.__esModule = true;` do not co-exist in my output, everything works.

My question is, what is the right solution? Why does this only affect older browsers? And why do they conflict?

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33087009/reactjs-babeljs-webpack-fails-on-android-4-0-x).

Comment: I'm not sure why that would fail. It's only assigned once at the start of a module, nothing should ever re-assign it, so that error is very strange. Are you able to see where it is throwing the actual error?

Comment: It throws in the first imported module where `exports.__esModule = true;` is present. I assume after the first `Object.defineProperty` is called that the shared exports object becomes read only so the assignment breaks in later modules that were built loosely (but only throws in the browsers mentioned). I might be completely missing the mark as I cannot seem to unearth anyone else with this issue beside the link provided.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about though. `exports` isn't shared, it should only ever be scoped into a single module.

Comment: I will set up a simple project with the issue later and attach it here to see if it reveals anything...thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`Object.defineProperty` is broken on some Android 4 stock browser versions and probably other browsers that made use of a buggy implementation in Webkit.

Check [this bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1530)
and [and this other one](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3334) reported to the chromium project.

The good news is you can apply [this polyfill](https://github.com/Financial-Times/polyfill-service/blob/master/packages/polyfill-library/polyfills/Object/defineProperty/polyfill.js) to fix the problem.

To make thing easy, you can simply copy and paste that polyfill on a `<script>` tag before your bundle.

This will fix your issues.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is, you need to install `babel-plugin-add-module-exports` and in your `.babelrc` register this plugin:

```
"plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports"
]
```

For more information visit [this website](https://github.com/59naga/babel-plugin-add-module-exports).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved to add babel-register library in entry points.

In webpack.config.js (Webpack 1.x version of configuration)

```
// As is
entry: {
  main: 'index.js'
},

// To be
entry: {
  main: ['babel-register', 'index.js']
},
```

Answer (score 0):

We met this problem on Android 4.0 and currently we cannot cut the support for Android 4.0.

For webpack 1.0, just set loose: true when you are using babel-preset-env.
However for Webpack 2, loose mode can't resolve this problem.

Finally, we found this trick, a little ugly.

```
// client_patch.js, For Android 4.0
var defineProperty = Object.defineProperty;
Object.defineProperty = function (exports, name) {
  if (name === '__esModule') {
    exports[name] = true;
    return;
  }
  return defineProperty.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

And in your webpack config file.

```
// webpack.config.js
entry: {
  main: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'client_patch.js'),
    'index.js'
  ]
}
```